# Copy keystore to docker container via Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to copy a keystore via DockerFile really important to point out that I am not trying to run my application via SSL, we are using the keystore to store some strings.

Dockerfile

```
    FROM openjdk:alpine
COPY './target/sistemaclave-api.jar' /usr/local
RUN chmod +x ./usr/local/sistemaclave-api.jar
WORKDIR /services/security/ && COPY keystore.keystore /usr/local/keystore.keystore
WORKDIR /
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10", "-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30", "-Xmx512m", "-Dspring.profiles.active=sistemactive", "./usr/local/sistemaclave-api.jar"]
```

Result

```
Building sistemaclave-api
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:alpine
 ---> 6a6a75aac6c9
Step 2/6 : COPY './target/sistemaclave-api.jar' /usr/local
 ---> 1df26898d59d
Removing intermediate container f6ebcbcca97b
Step 3/6 : RUN chmod +x ./usr/local/sistemaclave-api.jar
 ---> Running in 90b5bd148a62
 ---> 73dd00a6c103
Removing intermediate container 90b5bd148a62
Step 4/6 : WORKDIR /services/security/ && COPY keystore.keystore /usr/local/keystore.keystore
 ---> c31545034465
Removing intermediate container 7b3a60de737c
Step 5/6 : WORKDIR /
 ---> 5bdbed8b1d5a
Removing intermediate container fedac096df0c
Step 6/6 : CMD java -jar -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 -Xmx512m -Dspring.profiles.active=sistemactive ./usr/local/sistemaclave-api.jar
 ---> Running in 3d7cb6f7b412
 ---> 609fbf13a2fb
Removing intermediate container 3d7cb6f7b412

Successfully built 609fbf13a2fb
Successfully tagged sistemaclave-api:latest
```

When looking into the container I see the following:

```
/usr/local # ls
bin                   lib                   share                 sistemaclave-api.jar
```

I do not see the keystore at all in the defined path.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the `WORKDIR /services/security` in front of the `COPY` instruction?

Comment: Yes, move that up below COPY './target/sistemaclave-api.jar' /usr/local

Comment: ` Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:alpine
 ---> 6a6a75aac6c9
Step 2/6 : COPY './target/sistemaclave-api.jar' /usr/local
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1df26898d59d
Step 3/6 : RUN chmod +x ./usr/local/sistemaclave-api.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73dd00a6c103
Step 4/6 : COPY /services/security/credicorp.keystore /usr/local/keystore.keystore
ERROR: Service 'sistemaclave-api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder630585086/services/security/keystore.keystore: no such file or directory
[root@JAM1AX10I 4.1.1_projects]# `
 `

This is without the workdir

Comment: `Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:alpine
 ---> 6a6a75aac6c9
Step 2/5 : COPY './target/sistemaclave-api.jar' /usr/local
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1df26898d59d
Step 3/5 : COPY /services/security/keystore.keystore /usr/local/keystore.keystore
ERROR: Service 'sistemaclave-api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder944721244/services/security/keystore.keystore: no such file or directory
[root@JAM1AX10I 4.1.1_projects]#
```
I hope this is what you recommended from me to try

Comment: `Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:alpine
 ---> 6a6a75aac6c9
Step 2/6 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cd7ea86c7887
Step 3/6 : RUN cp '\services\security\credicorp.keystore' -r /usr/local/
 ---> Running in e85d80247276
cp: can't stat '\services\security\credicorp.keystore': No such file or directory
`
I have tried the following then i got this error.
I have added permissions to the folder thinking, maybe that's the issue. Unfortunately not..

Comment: Is any of the `services/security/keystore.keystore` a softlink directory or file in your case? If yes then it is not allowed

Comment: It is a file on the remote machine, not part of the Dockerfile's location.. Even tho i tried to do ../../  it didn't help. Gave me an error that it is forbidden to access external folder

Comment: I just used a different approach,

`--mount type=bind,src=/services/security/keystore.keystore,dst=/usr/local/keystore.keystore,bind-propagation=shared,readonly=true `